# What is the debian equivelent to ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

Googling it seems [a few others have asked this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/08/msg01494.html),

What is the Debian analogy of Ubuntu's `ubuntu-restricted-extras`? I'm trying to add the useful parts that are improperly licensed.

Comment: Are you asking “What is the debian equivalent to ubuntu-restricted-extras?”?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a metapackage. [You can see the actual software Ubuntu installs to satisfy `ubuntu-restricted-extras`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/ubuntu-restricted-extras),

- `libavcodec-extra`
  FFmpeg library with extra codecs (metapackage)
  also a virtual package provided by `libavcodec-extra58`
- `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
  Installer for Microsoft TrueType core fonts
- `unrar` Unarchiver for .rar files (non-free version)

It also further depends on [`ubuntu-restricted-addons`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/ubuntu-restricted-addons) which provides

- `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` Extra ffmpeg codecs for the Chromium Browser
- `gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3` Package not available
- `gstreamer1.0-libav` ffmpeg plugin for GStreamer
  `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
- `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` VA-API plugins for GStreamer

To install everything (except `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra` which isn't in the repos), you can run

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra \
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer       \
  unrar                           \
  gstreamer1.0-libav              \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly       \
  gstreamer1.0-vaapi;
```